# App not running in simulator for iOS 5

Tags: xcode, ios-simulator, ios5

When I run and build my application for the iOS 4.3 simulator everything works fine. Unfortunately when I run it in a iOS 5 simulator I get the following error:
[image]

It pauses and doesn't go further. The weird thing is that when I run it on my iPhone, which has iOS 5. Everything works fine.

Can you guys help me out?

Comment: I'm getting this too. Any resolution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I also faced the same issue.

It's resolved now by setting BaseSDK and DeploymentTarget  to IOS5.0.

Answer (score 3):

I had this problem as well.  I solved it by disabling "Enable Guard Malloc" in my scheme.